# How to run Matlab Scripts in condor cluster?

Tags: matlab, condor

I have an m-file main.m which does a very simple task: it sums two values and write the sum into a file. I have a .submit file with the contents below:

```
universe = Vanilla
Executable = /home/my_user/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab
Arguments = -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r run('./main.m'); quit
Rank = memory
initialdir=/home/my_user/test_condor
should_transfer_files = YES 
transfer_input_files = main.m
when_to_transfer_output = ON_EXIT 
notification = Complete
notify_user = myname@gmail.com
Output = $(Process).out 
Log = $(Process).log
Queue 1
```

The problem I am facing is the fact that, when I use the following command:

```
condor_submit main.submit
```

Nothing happens, it shows that a job was submitted and .out file is empty. The .log file only shows that the job was submitted from my IP.

Is there any problem with my .submit file? or in condor configuration?

Comment: Maybe try adding a `Error=$(process).err` line to see any error messages the Matlab process might be writing?  My only guess is that it might be a licensing issue.